# Can you store a LINQ query in a class?

Tags: c#, linq, class, properties

I am currently writing a csv parsing, C# code library and I was curious if you can store a linq query in a class member. So would something like this work?

Scenario:

```
class MyClass{
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public List<SomeOtherClassType> listQuery {get;set;}
}
```

Can I somehow store a linq query in that listQuery variable? The reason I ask is I don't want to keep the list in memory as it gets passed through different functions/methods. I only want it to be a list when I'm going to process and read data from it.

So could something like this be done.

```
 var classinstance = new MyClass(){ ID = SomeVar, listQuery = someEnumerable.Where(prop => prop == someValue };
```

This way, when I'm dealing with the "classinstance" variable, I want to perform a toList call, and write the properties output out to a file. There are probably better ways to do what I'm doing, but I'm wondering if this is possible.

Comment: I suppose we have a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284960) here. While storing the linq query works, it has disadvantages too (e.g. it will be evaluated every time anew and so on). Maybe you should tell us what do you **actually** want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, that would work fine. The return value of (most) LINQ queries is an `IEnumerable<T>`, which can be treated like an instance of any other class.

Of course, you'll want to change the type of `listQuery` to `IEnumerable<SomeOtherClassType>` instead of `List<SomeOtherClassType>`. If you keep it as the latter, then you'd need to call `ToList()` in order to store the results of the query, and this would execute the query immediately which isn't what you want to do.

Comment: The return type of the Linq query depends on the type on which the query was executed. There are actually 2 versions of each Linq method, those that extend on IEnumerable<T> (and return IEnumerable<T>)  and those that extend on IQueryable<T> (and return IQueryable<T>). This distinction could have a huge impact on an application, since the IEnumerable methods work in memory iterating collections, and the IQueryable methods recieve expressions that later get used by the provider. ( (DbSet<Foo> as IEnumerable<Foo>).Where(x=>x > 1) // filtered in memory. DbSet<Foo>.Where(x=>x > 1) //filtered in db